# Twilio Client - Connection accepted event on caller site

Tags: javascript, twilio, voip

I cannot find anthing in [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device) about event fired up when called user answers the call. Connection.accept(handler) is fired up only on called user browser when he anwsers. Im doing connection between two browsers in Aurelia.js and I want to start the timer on moment when call is answered, but none of the events described in docs seems to fire up when called user answers. This is my client code.

```
setupTwilio() {
    this.http.get("twilio/client/create").then(response => {
        this.twilioData = JSON.parse(response.response);

        Twilio.Device.setup(this.twilioData.token);

        Twilio.Device.offline((device)=>{
            Twilio.Device.destroy();
            this.setupTwilio();
        });

        Twilio.Device.ready((device) => {
          console.log("Ready");
        });

        Twilio.Device.error((error) => {
          console.log("Error: " + error.message);
        });

        Twilio.Device.connect((conn) => {
            this.call.startedAt = moment().unix();
        });

        Twilio.Device.disconnect((conn) => {
            this.rejectCall();

        });

        Twilio.Device.cancel((conn) => {
            this.rejectCall();

        });

        Twilio.Device.incoming((conn) => {
            var userId = conn.parameters.From.split(":").pop().substring(4);

            this.http.get('users/' + userId).then((response) => {
                this.call.user = JSON.parse(response.response);
                $('#incomingCall').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});

            }).catch(error => {
                this.notification.error("Error fetching user");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/introducing-call-progress-events-flexibly-track-and-control-your-outbound-calls.html It explains about call progress events: Initiated, Ringing, Answered, Completed.

Comment: Its not exacly what I need. Using the webhook I can let the backend know that user anwsered. And I need this info on frontend, for starting the timer and changing the call window view. Ofcourse, I can fetch this info from backend, but setting up another socket just to polifill that feature for Twilio seems like overkill.

Comment: I see... I don't find anything else either, you could set up something like socket.io or pubnub to create a channel that both browser listen too and push from the called user browser to receive it on the other browser.

Comment: To be honest, for now I did this in kinda lame way - timer is working and call window is since start in "ongoing call" state in caller app. And I post the informations about call length from the called user app. Its a little bit less secure in my case, but its only for information, call length limit is setted up by Twiml.

Anyway, thanks for help :)

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I would recommend using the call progress events here and sending them to the front end using Server Sent Events or Web Sockets as @ecorvo suggests.